# Adding Fragment In Second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment, manifest

when i adding fragment into second activity
android studio warn me "'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in 'com.example.midexam.MainActivity2'"

[image]

how to solve it, can i change it?

Comment: Post your code rather than attaching image. It will help other to test and compile the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one **onCreate** method inside an activity. Just remove the first onCreate and change setContentView to the correct layout.